# Javascript regex for symbol but not space

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test a string for a symbol (e.g. `$%^&*`) so I use the following regex that works well:

```
/[\W+]/.test(string)
```

However, a space is also matched with this regex. What I really want is to test for a symbol but not a space. I'm trying the following code, but a space is still matched:

```
/[\W\S+]/.test(string)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Define symbol. If you're only looking for `$%^&*`, why not just `/[\$%\^&\*]/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the whitespaces are included in `\W`, you need to use a negated character  class:

```
[^\w\s]
```

However, you must clearly define what you call a "symbol" since this character class include for example accentued letters and all out of the ascii range.

Answer (score 3):

`\W` is the equivalent of `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`, meaning "any character except these." So you can use `[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]` (note the space at the end) to exclude spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the inverse [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `\W` (which is `\w`) and use a negation in the character class:

```
/[^\w\s]+/.test(string)
```

Your regex `[\W\S+]` is also matching literal `+` as it is part of a character class. I think you need to place it outside the class to match 1 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

This regex may help you: `[^\s\w]`

https://regex101.com/r/jO4uU6/3

Comment: Yeah, I missed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also.

```
(?!\s)\W
```

This would match any non-word character but not of a space.

```
/(?:(?!\s)\W)+/.test(string)
```

ie, match one or more non-word characters but not of a space.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO4uU6/4)